# Jenkins: extended choice parameter - groovy - how to create file on the master

Tags: groovy, jenkins

i have a json string defined in the groovy script part of the 'extended choice parameter' plugin. Additionally I want to write the json config in a file on the master side inside the groovy script area. I thought, maybe the job directory would be the best place?

```
http://hudson/hudson/job/MY_JOB/config.json
```

If you ask now, why i should do this; the reason behind is, i don´t want the config pre-saved somewhere else. I don´t like the idea of configuring the file outside of the job config. I want to see/adjust configs at one place - in the job config.

I need many other informations from the json config for later use in a python code section within the same job.

**My questions are:**

- Am i following a wrong path here? Any suggestions?
- can i write directly the json config on the master side? It doesn´t have to be the jenkins job directory. I don´t care about the device/directory.
- if the approach is acceptable, how can i do this?

**The following code doesn´t work:**

```
def filename = "config.json"
def targetFile = new File(filename)

if (targetFile.createNewFile()) {
  println "Successfully created file $targetFile"    
} else {
  println "Failed to create file $targetFile"
}
```

**Remark:**

hudson.FilePath looks interesting!

http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/FilePath.html

Thanks for your help, Simon

Answer (score 0):

I got it:

```
import groovy.json.*

// location on the master : /srv/raid1/hudson/jobs
jsonConfigFile = new File("/srv/raid1/hudson/jobs/MY_JOB/config.json")
jsonConfigFileOnMaster = new hudson.FilePath( jsonConfigFile )

if( jsonConfigFileOnMaster.exists() ){
  jsonConfigFileOnMaster.delete()
}

jsonConfigFileOnMaster.touch( System.nanoTime())

jsonFormatted = JsonOutput.toJson( localJsonString )

jsonConfigFile.write jsonFormatted
```